# Karma - Unit Testing Angular Controller with Mocked API

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I wrote some unit tests for an angular factory that mock the response with a fake promise using $q.resolve({}). I'm now writing the controller test and want to call the factory from the controller and assign the resolved mock factory response to the controller scope (vm), and verify the data. Is this the proper way to test a factory from within a controller?

***factory test***

```
describe('getVICs()', function() {
  var vicFactory, $q, $httpBackend, result;
  beforeEach(module('vicModule'));
  beforeEach(inject(function(_vicFactory_, _$q_, _$httpBackend_) {
    vicFactory = _vicFactory_;
    $q = _$q_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
  }));
  beforeEach(function() {
    result = {};
    spyOn(vicFactory, 'getVICs').and.callThrough(function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      return deferred.promise;
    });
  });
  it('should be defined', function() {
    expect(vicFactory.getVICs()).toBeDefined();
  });
  it('should return list of vics', function() {
    var vicList = {
      "results": [
        {
          "version": 5
        },
        {
          "version": 1
        }
      ]
    };
    var qs = '?sort=version&dir=DESC&page=1&limit=10&status=ACTIVE';
    $httpBackend.expectGET('/path/to/my/api' + qs).respond(200, vicList);
    $httpBackend.whenGET('http://localhost:3000/path/to/my/api' + qs).respond(200, $q.when(vicList));
    vicFactory.getVICs(qs)
    .then(function(response) {
      result = response;
    });
    // flush pending HTTP requests
    $httpBackend.flush();
    expect(result.data.results).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

***factory***

```
function getVICs(query) {
  return $http.get('/path/to/my/api' + query)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response;
  });
}
```

***controller test***

```
describe('vicController', function() {
  var $controller, vicController, vicFactory, $q, $scope, $httpBackend, deferred;
  var vicList = {
    "results": [
      {
        "version": 5
      },
      {
        "version": 1
      }
    ]
  };
  var qs = '?sort=version&dir=DESC&page=1&limit=10&status=ACTIVE';
  beforeEach(module('vicModule'));
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _vicFactory_, _$q_, _$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_, _$httpParamSerializer_) {
    $controller = _$controller_;
    vicFactory = {
      getVICs: function () {
        deferred = $q.defer();
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    };
    $q = _$q_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $httpParamSerializer = _$httpParamSerializer_;
    spyOn(vicFactory, 'getVICs').and.callThrough();
    vicController = $controller('vicController', {vicFactory: vicFactory});
    deferred.resolve(vicList);
  }));
  it('should be defined', function() {
    expect(vicController).toBeDefined();
  });
  it('should call getVICs() on load', function() {
    $httpBackend.expectGET(''/path/to/my/api?' + qs).respond(200, vicList);
    $scope.$digest();
    expect(vicFactory.getVICs).toHaveBeenCalledWith(qs);
    expect($scope.vicList).toEqual(vicList);
  });
});
```

***controller***

```
  angular.module('vicModule')
  .controller('vicController', vicController);
  vicController.$inject = [
    'vicFactory'
  ];

  function vicController(vicFactory) {
    var vm = this;
    var qs = '?sort=version&dir=DESC&page=1&limit=10&status=ACTIVE';
    vicFactory.getVICs(qs)
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log('vic controller success');
      console.log(response);
      vm.vicList = response;
    }, function(response) {
      console.log('vic controller error');
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
```

***Fixed***

Got this working by injecting $q and $scope, setting vicFactory in beforeEach, updating spy, and then resolving the deferred with the expected data set after controller initialization. The controller test spec has been updated, hope this help someone.

Comment: You need to inject $q into your controller test. then you need to do expect(vicFactory.getVICS).and.returnValue(vicList); in your test case.

Comment: Injecting $q was part of the problem, thanks!